# How to programmatically check Android "Location Consent"?

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location

I would like to programmatically determine whether the user has agreed or disagreed to the "Location Consent" dialog that appears when you turn your on your GPS on Android devices.

I have not been able to find where to get this information from, and I'm not sure whether it *is* actually available anywhere within the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is about location mode. if the user agreed to the "Location Consent", location mode set on High Accuracy.

For check this mode you can use following code:

```
    public static boolean checkLocationSettings(Context context) {

    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF && locationMode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY); //check location mode

    }else{
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the newer gms.location.SettingsApi. You build a LocationRequest and ask if the current system settings are compatible, and handle the result as needed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html